# Can't get html5 data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I am trying to get html5 custom data attribute with jQuery.These attributes are set to element from database. They are injected in html element, but jQuery can't see them.

So here is my html element with custom data attrs:

```
<a data-price={{$product->price}} data-brand={{$product->brand . " " . $product->model}} id="model" data-toggle="modal" href="#shoppingcart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Add to Cart</a>
```

But with jQuery I get undefined value:

```
$("a#modal").on("click",function() {
            console.log($(this).data("price"));
});
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: ID is model not modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This element has no ID `modal`. Try `model` instead, with `e`, the HTML has  `id="model"`

Try this:

```
$("a#model").on("click",function() {
    console.log($(this).data("price"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio - I,ve been working whole day to finish this project and somehow did't see that small typo - it is time for rest and lunch :).

Comment: @carousel, yeah, sometimes its nice to have a new pair of eyes looking at the code :) Feel free to accept if it solved your problem. Cheers.